# Why does the git client open local repositories in the /run/ folder?

Tags: linux, git, flatpak

I have a repository in a folder */var/www/*. Through the git client, I select this folder as "open an existing repository", but the repository opens as if it is located in the */run/* directory.

This did not happen on the old computer. And now I have a number of problems. For example, auto-updating of the state of files after their modification does not work. It also fails to use Stash. There are also other problems.

> **UPDATE and a solution:** I found out that this problem appeared due to the fact that I installed the flatpack version of Sublime Merge on
> a new computer. When I reinstalled it as a regular package, everything
> works as it should.

I'm not sure if the problem is exactly in the changed repository path, but this is my main suspicion.

I'm using Linux Mint 21.1. Test this with git-clients Sublime Merge and Gittyup. Sublime Merge shows the path to repositories as */run/user/1000/doc/c9e48011/<repo_name>*.

[image: sublime merge]

Gittyup as */run/flatpak/doc/c9e48011/<repo_name>*.

[image: Gittyup]

On the path from Sublime Merge, there really is a folder with all the files from my repository. And the path that Gittyup shows is inaccessible because the */run/flatpak/* folder doesn't actually exist.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: What git client are you using?

Comment: "when I open this repository through the git client" What *exactly* are you doing? Please describe a specific set of commands or user interface actions.

Comment: Follow [ask] and [answer]

Comment: @Mat I used Sublime Merge. Then I tried Gittyup and got a similar problem. I edited the question and described it in more detail. But I have already realized that this is a specificity of the flatpak versions of these programs.